# Get VPN Ip address

Tags: c#, vpn, network-interface

How can i get the ip from a PPP or PPPT vpn connection?

I know the name of the VPN connection, so how can i filter

```
var nics = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
```

to only get the vpn interface with the name "VPNConnection", and get the given ip address?

Comment: have you tried any code at all..? here is a hint on what you could try / google `foreach (var item in System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())` try that and report back if you have further issues this is a pretty easy task believe it or not..

Comment: `using System.Net.NetworkInformation;` may need to add this as well

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
using System.Linq;

var vpn = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
                          .First(x => x.Name == "VPNConnection");
```

EDIT: Whoops I didn't finish:

```
var ip = vpn.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses.First(x => x.Address.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork).Address.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made an application for this case. Using the batch file with following command, I made a process that executes the .bat file and stores the ip in variable ip

```
            //make a batch file and write this in it
        File.WriteAllText(FolderPath + "\\getip.bat", "@echo off \r\n FOR /F \"tokens=1-6 delims=:. \" %%a in ('netsh int ip show address \"SanadConnectVPN\" ^|find \"IP Address\"') do set IP=%%c.%%d.%%e.%%f \r\n echo %IP%");

        var newProcess = new Process
        {
            StartInfo =
            {
                FileName = FolderPath + "\\getip.bat",
                WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
            }
        };
        newProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        newProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        newProcess.Start();
        string ip = newProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        newProcess.WaitForExit();
        MessageBox.Show(ip);
        return ip
```